# Autoscroll a TextArea to youngest/freshest row/line

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to use a **TextArea** UI widget as a UI integrated Logger.
Therefore the TextArea should always show the youngest message.

I browsed the whole API to find the proper method but could not find any.
**TextArea$setCursorPosition** while passing **TextArea$getLines** as its parameter did not worked as intended.

I read about **TextArea$setPrefRows** and used it with getLines but also no luck.

How can I use TextArea to get autoscroll behaviour down to the most recent line?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation in a game I was working on, and what I ended up doing was putting the TextArea in a ScrollPane and then adding an action with each line to scroll it to the bottom (there appears to be a bit of a bug in setting the position).

```
spMessages.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(0.0f), new Action() {
  @Override
  public boolean act(float delta) {
    spMessages.setScrollPercentY(1.0f);
    return true;
  }
}));
```

A bit of a hack, but I chalked it up as "a cool UI effect" :)

Comment: Hey buddy! Thanks for the advice. Sadly it does not work. Please check my https://pastebin.com/ZbyjG2u3 maybe you can point out what I am still missing - I like your approach neitherless!

Comment: Does not work meaning nothing happens? I assume you're updating the stage in your update method?

Comment: Something is happening. The first lines of the log I want to see are being show. But all following are cut off. So there is no downscrolling happening. I update my stage.act() and stage.draw() in the render() method. See this paste: https://pastebin.com/b5yAuprt